# Best SQL query to get unique sets from below table

Tags: sql, oracle, set-theory

I have a below table

```
Select X,Y from T
X | Y
------
1 | 2     
1 | 3      
2 | 1     
3 | 5     
3 | 1
```

Column X and Y holds Strings, I gave numbers just for example.

I need output from this table as below

```
1,2

1,3

3,5
```

i,e, Unique sets from the table. Out of Row 1 (1,2) and Row 3 (2,1), I need only one set, because (1,2)=(2,1) in my set. Similarly (1,3)=(3,1).
So unique sets in this table are (1,2) (1,3) and (3,5).

I tried below SQL, let me know if there is a better way, as I am not sure whether I can use '>' or '<' with ROWID

```
SELECT X||','||Y FROM T t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T t2
WHERE t1.X=t2.Y AND t1.Y=t2.X and t1.ROWID>t2.ROWID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct least(x,y), greatest(x,y)
from the_table;
```

`least()` and `greatest()` put the values into an order so that 1,2 and 2,1 are returned as 1,2. The `distinct` then removes the duplicates

Comment: I gave numbers as example, Column X and Y holds strings

Comment: then you probably need to start joining your tables, if you provide us with your table definition and some values we can probably help you better @KishorKumar

Comment: Works :) Thanks, a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Kishor: You may wish to include UPPER (or LOWER) around each column if ('a', 'B') is considered equivalent to ('A', 'b')

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT gets you distinct rows, so all you need to do is to have your pairs ordered, first the smaller then the larger. You do this with LEAST and GREATEST.

```
select distinct least(x,y) || ',' || greatest(x,y)
from t;
```

Comment: Why concatenate the values? Seems totally unnecessary.

Comment: @Boneist Because OP posted his desired output as comma separated values ;-)